# Unix command to check if any two lines in a file are same?

Tags: text-processing, search

Is there a unix command that can check if any two lines in a file are the same?

For e.g. Consider a file `sentences.txt`

```
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence Z
This is sentence X
This is sentence A
This is sentence B
```

We see that the sentence

```
This is sentence X
```

is repeated.

Is there any command that can quickly detect this, so that I can perhaps execute it like this -

```
$ cat sentences.txt | thecommand
Line 1:This is sentence X
Line 4:This is sentence X
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is one  way to get the exact output you're looking for:

```
$ grep -nFx "$(sort sentences.txt | uniq -d)" sentences.txt 
1:This is sentence X
4:This is sentence X
```

Explanation:

The inner `$(sort sentences.txt | uniq -d)` lists each line that occurs more than once. The outer `grep -nFx` looks again in `sentences.txt` for exact `-x` matches to any of these lines `-F` and prepends their line number `-n`

Comment: Your edit just barely beat me from posting the exact same answer. +1

Comment: So the $(command) syntax works as a kind of replacement?

Comment: @CodeBlue - yes. It's called [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Comment: `sort sentences.txt | uniq -d | grep -nFxf - sentences.txt` would be a little more efficient and would avoid potential `arg list too long` problems.

Answer (score 10):

Not exactly what you want, but you can try combining `sort` and `uniq -c -d`:

```
aularon@aularon-laptop:~$ cat input
This is sentence X
This is sentence Y
This is sentence Z
This is sentence X
This is sentence A
This is sentence B

aularon@aularon-laptop:~$ sort input | uniq -cd
      2 This is sentence X
aularon@aularon-laptop:~$
```

`2` here is the number of duplications found for the line, from `man uniq`:

```
   -c, --count
          prefix lines by the number of occurrences

   -d, --repeated
          only print duplicate lines
```

Answer (score 6):

IF the file contents fit in memory `awk` is good for this. The standard one-liner in comp.lang.awk (I can't search an instance from this machine but there's several every month) to just detect there is duplication is `awk 'n[$0]++'` which counts the occurrences of each line value and prints any occurrence(s) other than the first, because the default action is `print $0`.

To show all occurrences including the first, in your format, but possibly in mixed order when more than one value is duplicated, gets a little more finicky:

```
awk <sentences.txt ' !($0 in n) {n[$0]=NR;next} \
    n[$0] {n[$0]=0; print "Line "n[$0]":"$0} \
    {print "Line "NR":"$0} '
```

Shown in multiple lines for clarity, you usually run together in real use.
If you do this often you can put the `awk` script in a file with `awk -f`, or of course the whole thing in a shell script. Like most simple `awk` this can be done very similarly with `perl -n[a]`.